# Auto-populate the frame titles from subsection titles

Tags: beamer, header-footer, sectioning

Is there a way to make `\frametitle` automatically take the `\subsection` heading?

Or maybe equivalently, is there a way to make the section\subsection titles in the header larger? I am afraid the audience may not follow the section\subsection title.

Thanks! (FWIW, so far I've been using the Warsaw theme)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\let\insertframetitle\insertsubsectionhead}{}
```

will replace all frame titles, as far as they exist, but will not magically make a frame title appear if you don't give the argument to the frame environment or give a \frametitle{} command.

ETA: Additionally adding

```
\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother
```

makes every frame have a title, even if it is \relax by default. (This is somewhat hackish.)

Comment: Is there a way to stop this routine modifying the looks of "\titlepage" and "\sectionpage"? Because currently it adds an empty ribbon on top of the frame.