# Automatic frame titles and subtitles

Tags: beamer

Is there a way to automatically use the section name as the frame title and the subsection name as the frame subtitle?

I think [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/auto-populate-the-frame-titles-from-subsection-titles) is related, but when I tried to hack that solution to change the substitution from `\insertsubsectionhead` to `\insertsectionhead` as follows, my frame title simply disappeared:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
   \let\insertframetitle\insertsectionhead}{}
```

(later)

```
\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{}

. . .
```

Does it matter where that template manipulation appears?  I have it in my preamble right after I choose my theme.

Bottom line: I have no idea how these internals work, so worst case I'll just continue duplicating the sections and subsection names into the frame titles and subtitles.  I like the idea of keeping that connection back to the outline in every frame.

Answer (score 18):

To use section and subsection names in frame title in beamer, one can use `\secname` and `\subsecname` as shown below:

```
\section{About project}
\subsection{Easy stuff}
\begin{frame}{\secname : \subsecname}
    ...
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 13):

As the answer in the question you linked explains, it is not enough to add simply

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
   \let\insertframetitle\insertsectionhead}{}
```

this will work if you explicitly use a `\frametitle{}` command for each frame. The same answer explains how to avoid using the command explicitly by adding

```
\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother
```

So, in your case, you'll have to add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
   \let\insertframetitle\insertsectionhead}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
   \let\insertframesubtitle\insertsubsectionhead}{}


\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gonzalo.  I think there must be something about the theme that I am using or something because I can't get it to work.  I did try the empty `\frametitle{}` without the extra `\makeatletter` command before, so I guess I understood something about what was said there in the older answer, but it did not have the desired effect.  I am using the Madrid theme, and I did try your solution with the default theme, but now the title bar is not even there.  I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.  If you have any suggestions I'll be glad to work with you.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @NeilBest for some reason, I only read you comment today; I apologize. If you are still interested in this issue, please edit your question by adding a complete but simple document showing the problem you mentioned.

Comment: Wow, very professional! A question: How can I add the section-number here (in the last code-block)?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've used your answer to my presentation and it worked very well. However, I want the final frame not to include any title (now it includes the title of my final section). I used \begin{frame}[plain], but it doesn't change nothing. Is there a solution for this issue?