# How to show previous and next titles in infolines outter theme?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, navigation

The infolines theme shows the section and subsection titles in the header, in one single line, preceding the title for the frame (in the second line).

I'd like to show also the titles of the previous and next section and subsection (in a transparent way) to give some context, similarly to what the split header theme does (but restricted to only the previous and next elements).

I think I have seen this somewhere but only on the PDF not in the code.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Very related question: [Accessing other slides' titles in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15778/3323)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54950/only-3-items-in-navigation-bar-is-that-possible), using two new counters and commands `\prevsection` and `\nextsection`, as well as a serie of commands to define what you want to appear in your header.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not fully satisfied with that solution, it requires redundant information and I should replicate it for subsections (and I don't really understand that code). If I have to read such a kind of code I prefer checking [the original template](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/src/aa6ea796e825dda61648d4edf83d64e4cbd7d4d0/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty?at=default). The next day I can work on this I'll search for the definition of `\insertsectionhead` and `\insertsectionnavigation`.