# How to insert automatically, in somewhere in one of the slide's corner, the frametitle of the next slide

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I would like to insert in one of the slide's corner the frametitle of the next slide. The motivation of this is that I would have a tip of the content of the next slide and so I would be able to link better the speak dedicated to each slide.

In this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15778/accessing-other-slides-titles-in-beamer), there is a solution on how to retrive the frametitle of others slides from one current slide. Now, I would like to achieve some automation in this process and I would like to the frametitle to appear in the down right coner of the frame slide, together e just left of the numbering.

Any tips on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> The following answer is based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16933/36296

If you want the frametitle to be next to the framenumber, you could define your own footline. Of course the definition heavily depends on the theme you use, but as you did not provide any code in your question, I choose a plain text one for the following answer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{frm}{\string\frametitleentry{\the\c@framenumber}{#1}{#2}}}}{}{}
\newcommand*{\frametitleentry}[3]{\@namedef{frametitleshort#1}{#2}\@namedef{frametitle#1}{#3}}
\AtEndDocument{\if@filesw\newwrite\tf@frm\immediate\openout\tf@frm\jobname.frm\relax\fi}
\@input{\jobname.frm}
\newcommand*{\insertpreviousframetitle}[1][1]{\bgroup\advance\c@framenumber by -#1\relax\@ifstar{\@nameuse{frametitleshort\the\c@framenumber}\egroup}{\@nameuse{frametitle\the\c@framenumber}\egroup}}
\newcommand*{\insertnextframetitle}[1][1]{\bgroup\advance\c@framenumber by #1\relax\@ifstar{\@nameuse{frametitleshort\the\c@framenumber}\egroup}{\@nameuse{frametitle\the\c@framenumber}\egroup}}
\makeatother


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill \insertnextframetitle\quad\insertframenumber\quad}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test1}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test2}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test3}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test4}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]