# Automatic frame titles subtitles, with condition

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to set up automatic frame titles and subtitles as follows:

- If a frame has a title or subtitle set (even to `{}`, it is used).
- If subsection title is not empty, use section title as a frame subtitle, and subsection title as a frame title.
- Otherwise, use section title as a frame title, frame does not have a subtitle.

Here is a code that I tried (does not follow the first rule above, taken from [Automatic frame titles and subtitles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15427/automatic-frame-titles-and-subtitles?rq=1)). It does not work as expected — with `\subsection*{}` frame title is empty and frame subtitle is set to section title.

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \ifx\insertsubsection\empty
    \let\insertframetitle\insertsectionhead
  \else
    \let\insertframetitle\insertsubsectionhead
  \fi
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \ifx\insertsubsection\empty
  \else
    \let\insertframesubtitle\insertsectionhead
  \fi
}{}

\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{%
    \global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar%
    \bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 9):

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
  \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{%
    \global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar%
    \bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \ifx\insertframetitle\empty
    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\empty
      \ifx\insertsubsection\empty 
        \frametitle{\insertsectionhead}
      \else
        \frametitle{\insertsubsectionhead}\framesubtitle{\insertsectionhead}
      \fi  
    \else     
    \fi  
    \else
    \fi
 }{}

\begin{document}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}
Frame with frametitle and framesubtitle set (section and subsection are ignored)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
%\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}
Frame with framesubtitle only (section and subsection are ignored). 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
%\frametitle{title}
%\framesubtitle{subtitle}
Frame with no frametitle, no framesubtitle, part of a subsection (subsection title is used as frametitle and section title as framesubtitle) 
\end{frame}

\section{section}
\begin{frame}
%\subsection{subsection}
%\frametitle{title}
%\framesubtitle{subtitle}
Frame with no frametitle, no framesubtitle and not part of a subsection. Section title is used as frametitle. 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It also works if you have a `\subsection*{}` (i.e. in such a case it still shows
section name as frame subtitle if no title or subtitle are present. It does not work if you have both `\frametitle{}` and `\framesubtitle{}`, i.e. in such a case it will show section or subsection name as frame title. But maybe this can be workarounded with no harm replacing `\frametitle{}` with `\frametitle{~}`.