# Section automatically inserted as frametitle in beamer

Tags: beamer

I managed to repeat [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146682/87994) for customizing a beamer style. Now I would like to automatically insert the section and sub-section titles in the head of each slide, without necessity of setting `\frametitle`, ideally through the `.sty` files (i.e. beamer outer theme) and not in the `.tex` file.

I adapted the `beamerouterthemetexsx.sty` of the cited example in this way (see the comments):

```
\mode<presentation>

% Frame title
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{texsx}[1][]
{
\vskip1cm%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.2cm]{frametitle} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox[fill=white](0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2);
  \fill[orange] (0,0) rectangle(2.95,1.2);
  \fill[blue!50!cyan!80] (3.05,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2);
   % In the next part I replaced \insertframetitle by \insertsection
   % In the same way I replaced \insertframesubtitle by \insertsubsection
   \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      {\node[anchor=west, white,font=\large] at (3.2,0.61){\insertsection};}
      \else%
      {\node[anchor= west, white,font=\large] at (3.2,0.81){\insertsection};%
       \node[anchor= west, white,font=\small] at
       (3.2,0.41){\insertsubsection};}%
      \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\mode<all>
```

My document's source looks like this:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{My first attempt}
\date[today]{\today}
\author[Miguel]{Miguel Alvarez}

% use custom theme
\usetheme{texsx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{The first lesson}

\subsection{Before the first break}

\begin{frame}
Blank frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{auto}
Frame with title
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{auto}{auto}
Frame with title and sub-title
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there a simple way to get automatically the title and subtitle in a slide by `\begin{frame}` without necessity of setting frame title and subtitle, which won't be used in any case (as by `\begin{frame}{auto}{auto}`)?

In other words, for the code

```
\begin{frame}
Blank frame
\end{frame}
```

I got:

[image]

**BUT** I was expecting:

[image]

Comment: Well, I am not sure I understand your problem ... I tried to compile your example (using the theme you proposed) and it failed. So I added `\RequirePackage` in your `.sty` just after `\mode<presentation>` and replaced `\usetheme{texsx}` with `\useoutertheme{texsx}` and everything seems to work fine. Or I totally missed your question.

Comment: I was expecting to get a slide with title and sub-title already after the title slide. The example is to show that in the current version I need to set a frame title (`auto` is the one) and frame sub-title to get the head-bar, although section and subsection are already set.

Comment: Could you edit your question with a visual output of what you would like ?

Comment: Ok, I see, the solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15429/141947) seems to work in your case.

Comment: Thanks [@BambOo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/141947/bamboo) I had seem this solution and I though, it may work only at `.tex` preamble, which is not the optimal way. I inserted the suggested lines in `beamerthemetexsx.sty` and it is working **but** only for the section and not for the sub-section.

Comment: Could you edit your snippet to reflect the modified code ?

Comment: Any news ??????

Comment: Sorry @BambOo for leaving the discussion but I went busy and in the meantime I think, that it is not bad at all to have the option of a fully blank slide, despite the longer code for "normal" slides. Thus I used `\begin{frame}[t]{auto}{auto}` for start a slide in the desired layout.